# Restrict joined and grouped SQL results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `Sales` which has an `ID` for each sale and its date. I have another, called `SaleDetail`, which has the details of each sale: the `Article` and the `Quantity` sold. I want to show a list of all the articles and quantities of them that were sold between two dates. I'm using:

```
 SELECT  
 SaleDetail.Article,  
 SUM(SaleDetail.Quantity) AS Pieces  
 FROM  
 SaleDetail  
 JOIN Sales ON Sales.ID = SaleDetail.ID  
 GROUP BY SaleDetail.Article  
 HAVING Sales.Date BETWEEN '10-01-2013' AND '20-01-2013'
```

But it seems to have logical errors, because I get "'Sales.Date' in clause HAVING is not valid, because it is not contained in an aggregate function or in the GROUP BY clause" How should I do it? Thank you.

Comment: The `ON Sales.ID = SaleDetail.ID` looks wrong. Are you sure the tables are to be joined on those columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the condition is supposed to be in where clause, but not having clause.
Having only to groups as a whole, whereas the WHERE clause applies to individual rows. Here you are looking for rows with the specific dates.

```
SELECT
SaleDetail.Article,
SUM(SaleDetail.Quantity) AS Pieces
FROM
SaleDetail
JOIN Sales ON Sales.ID = SaleDetail.ID
where Sales.Date BETWEEN '10-01-2013' AND '20-01-2013'
GROUP BY SaleDetail.Article
```

Comment: @Sonam there is a time limit on which the op can't mark an answer as the accepted one. This limitation is there on purpose, to give time for more answers, so please, don't ask a user to mark your answer as the accepted one 6 minutes after you posted it

Comment: Thanks Lamak, I was not aware of that. I only ask to mark it because many times users forget or not aware.

Answer (score 1):

The HAVING Clause is for use when trying to filter on an Aggregate.  In this case, Sales.Date is not being aggregated.  So you can just use WHERE.

```
SELECT
SaleDetail.Article,
SUM(SaleDetail.Quantity) AS Pieces
FROM
SaleDetail
JOIN Sales ON Sales.ID = SaleDetail.ID
WHERE Sales.Date BETWEEN '10-01-2013' AND '20-01-2013'
GROUP BY SaleDetail.Article
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable in the `having` clause needs to be in the `group by` clause. Put the `Sales.Date` expression in a `where` clause instead.

Comment: But where is the variable in Having clause?

Comment: See the other answers, notice there is no `having`. `having` is not required just because there is a `group by`. Think: `having` is the `group by`'s `where`. And, w're not grouping on the date column so we can use it in a `where` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @SaleDetail table  (ID int, Article varchar(40), Quantity int  )
declare @Sales table  (ID int, Quantity int , [Date] Date )

SELECT
SaleDetail.Article,
SUM(SaleDetail.Quantity) AS Pieces
FROM
@SaleDetail SaleDetail
JOIN @Sales Sales ON Sales.ID = SaleDetail.ID
WHERE Sales.Date BETWEEN '2013-01-10' AND '2013-01-20'
GROUP BY SaleDetail.Article
```